# Dealing with noisy/mislabelled dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, outliers

I have several datasets where each instance has numeric label assigned by a human that can take values between 1 and 5. After doing a manual inspection of one of these datasets, I noticed the following:

- The instances labelled as 1 and 2 are very similar, as well as the data between labels 4 and 5. It seems that the 5-item label set should be reduced to a 3-item one.
- Several instances are wrongly labelled: This instances have extreme feature values that have no relation to the labelled assigned.

At this point, I'm looking for an automated way of "normalizing" the label set and to identify wrongly labelled instances after this normalization is applied. Is there a standard approach for these problems?